# Why doesn´t indexOf work?

Tags: knockout.js

in the code below; why is "self.ticketCollection.indexOf(t)" in the "self.Addticket-function always -1  ???

After page_load, I push New (newTicket), then ADD (addTicket). This works fine and a record of ("ny","-1") is added to my ticketCollection. Then when I repeat this another record exactly the same is added. Debugger (FireBug) tells me "self.ticketCollection.indexOf(t)" is -1 in both cases. Why?

```
function Ticket(ticketname, cost) {
    var self = this;

    //alert("ikke implementer fullt ut ennå!");

    self.ticketname = ko.observable(ticketname);
    self.cost= ko.observable(cost);

} // end Ticket

//==============================================================

function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

//------ initiate ----------------------------------------------

// the product we want to view/edit
self.selectedTicket = ko.observable();

self.ticketCollection = ko.observableArray(
    [
        new Ticket("Bus", "$2"),
        new Ticket("Ferry", "$3"),
        new Ticket("Bicycle", "$1")
    ]);

// selected item from ticket list-view
self.listViewSelectedItem = ko.observable();

// push any changes in the list view to our main selectedTicket
self.listViewSelectedItem.subscribe(function (ticket) {
    if (ticket) {
        self.selectedTicket(ticket);
    }
}); // self.listViewSelectedItem.subscribe //


//---- NEW button pressed --------------------------------------
self.newTicket = function () {

        // create a new instance of a Ticket
        var t = new Ticket("ny", "-1");

        // set the selected Ticket to out new instance
        self.selectedTicket(t);

    }.bind(this);

//---- ADD to collection -----------------------------------------

self.addTicket = function () {
        //alert("ADD is pushed!");

        // get a reference to out currently selected product
        var t = self.selectedTicket();

        // ignore if null
        if (!t) { return; }

        // check to see that the ticket doesn\t already exist
        if (self.ticketCollection.indexOf(t) > -1) {
            return;
        }

        // add the product to the collection
        self.ticketCollection.push(t);

        // clear out the selected product
        self.selectedTicket(t);
        //self.listViewSelectedItem(t)

    };
} // end ViewModel
```

Thanx in advance!

Asle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you have two `Ticket` objects that contain the exact same values, does not mean these two objects are equal. This is why the `indexOf` returns -1 every time -- because the `ticketCollection` observable array does NOT contain the exact item you are checking for. This SO question has a good explanation of JavaScript object equality: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-do-you-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Instead of using the `indexOf` on the array, you should instead check to see if any item in your `ticketCollection` matches BOTH the `ticketName` and the `cost` of the new, incoming Ticket.

I'll add an example of what I mean:

```
for(var i=0, len=self.ticketCollection().length; i < len; i++){
if ((t.ticketname() === ticketCollection()[i].ticketname()) && (t.cost() === ticketCollection()[i].cost())) {
    alert('Found the object in the observable array')
}
```